# How can push value to array in reducer function (React js , Typescript , Redux)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

can anyone help me. I have a product list and I want to choose some favorite products for my cart.
but product is an object, and shopping cart is an object array. how can i fix it?

here is my reducer function

```
interface Istate {
    favorites?:SingleProductDataType[]
}

const initialState:Istate = {}

export const cardReducer = (state:Istate = initialState, action:CardDispatchType):Istate => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CARD:
            return {
                favorites: [...action.payload]
            }
    
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

---------here is my action function

```
export const addToCard = (product:SingleProductDataType) => async(dispatch:Dispatch<CardDispatchType>) => {
    dispatch({type:ADD_TO_CARD, payload: product})
}
```

---that's my actiontypes

```
export const ADD_TO_CARD = "ADD_TO_CARD"


export interface AddToCard {
    type: typeof ADD_TO_CARD;
    payload: SingleProductDataType
}

export type CardDispatchType = AddToCard
```

Comment: favorites: [...state.favorites, ...action.payload]

Comment: SingleProductDataType must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Comment: but generally you are learning a very outdated style of redux there that makes you write a multitude of the code modern redux would require. you are probably following a very outdated tutorial. please follow the official redux tutorials at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index instead.

Comment: thanks but it is not solution

Comment: @Samir the solution would be `return { favorites: [...state.favourites, action.payload]   }` or with (and only there!) modern redux'es `createSlice`: `state.favorites.push(action.payload)` (in legacy redux, this would be a bug, in modern redux it is possible)

Comment: @phry i also tired this  return { favorites: [...state.favourites, action.payload]   }   but it does not work

Comment: change your initial state to `{ favorites: [] }` - it won't spread if it's undefined

Comment: and especially when using TypeScript: PLEASE look into modern redux after resolving that. TypeScript with vanilla redux is a real pain compared to modern.

Comment: @phry first of all i wanna thank u for everything . it really worked and right now i'll start to learn modern redux :D

Answer (score 0):

`return { ...state, favorites: [...action.payload]}`

Comment: type 'object' must have a ' symbol.iterator ()' method that returns an iterator